# Issue with numericality validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, client-side-validation

I am using gem client_side_validation in my rails 5.1 app. I am using a validation numericality on a field as following:

```
{greater_than: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 2_147_483_647, only_integer: true}
```

Problem is that client side js allows user to add , separated format integer values but server side validation give error message.

> Not A Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in gem client side validation. for more details please see [this](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations/issues/717) link.